# How to show the length of the text at run time even it was edited and deleted in java gui programming?

Tags: java

The problem is how to show the length of the text at run time even it was edited or deleted in java gui programming. Please help to fix the problem.

So here's the code:

```
area1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            update();

        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            update();
        }

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            update();
        }
        public void update()
        {
            lblLength.setText(area1.getText().length()+"\160");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Length as in number of characters, length in pixels? What kind of length? How about an example?

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you elaborate or perhaps show some code and what is not working?

Comment: And what's not working?

Answer (score 0):

**This is actually wrong and should not be done this way but I will leave it here for future reference**

Fairly easy. You just have a KeyTyped listener and every time it gets triggered you update the number of chars.

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jMainPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jCharsTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jCharsNumLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jCharsNumCounterLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jCharsTextField.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                jCharsTextFieldKeyTyped(evt);
            }
        });

        jCharsNumLabel.setText("Chars #:");

        jCharsNumCounterLabel.setText(" ");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jMainPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jMainPanel);
        jMainPanel.setLayout(jMainPanelLayout);
        jMainPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jMainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jMainPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jMainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                    .addComponent(jCharsTextField)
                    .addComponent(jCharsNumLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jCharsNumCounterLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(303, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jMainPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            jMainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jMainPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jCharsTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jMainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jCharsNumLabel)
                    .addComponent(jCharsNumCounterLabel))
                .addContainerGap(242, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jMainPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jMainPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jCharsTextFieldKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                         
        jCharsNumCounterLabel.setText(Integer.toString(jCharsTextField.getText().length()));
    }                                        

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jCharsNumCounterLabel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jCharsNumLabel;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jCharsTextField;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jMainPanel;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

This is your point of interest:

```
private void jCharsTextFieldKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                         
        jCharsNumCounterLabel.setText(Integer.toString(jCharsTextField.getText().length()));
    }
```

Comment: You should never use a KeyListener with text components, it could be consumed before your notified and doesn't take into account the user pasting text into the field. The use of a DocumentListener demonstrate by the OP is actually the correct means

Comment: @user3741964 check MadProgrammer's answer, that's the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is keep track of the length of the content of the `JTextArea` then the `DocumentListener` is the correct approach, for example...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.Document;

public class TextAreaLength {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TextAreaLength();
    }

    private JLabel lengthLabel;
    private JTextArea ta;

    public TextAreaLength() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                ta = new JTextArea(10, 20);
                ta.setWrapStyleWord(true);
                ta.setLineWrap(true);
                lengthLabel = new JLabel("0");
                ta.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                        update(e.getDocument());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                        update(e.getDocument());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                        update(e.getDocument());
                    }

                    protected void update(Document doc) {
                        lengthLabel.setText(Integer.toString(doc.getLength()));
                    }

                });
                lengthLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(ta);
                frame.add(lengthLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

If this isn't working for you then either you've done something else wrong in your code that you're not showing us or you've not stated the problem well enough for us to understand